# Why StripLines does not work after clicking Reset button in WindowsForm application by using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, reset, mschart

I plotted a graph and add Zoom,reset and select chart area by using StripLines.out put window is as below,[image: output]

So I can select area and add tick for X-Zoom and Y-Zoom then click reset and select area again then that function are working well.but I off the tick from Zoom and select again area.then could not select area.
Why is that?I am a beginner for this language.any help.very appreciated.

This is my code Zoom

```
private void checkBoxXZoom_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChartArea CA1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

            if (this.checkBoxXZoom.Checked == true)
            {
                CA1.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                CA1.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
                CA1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                CA1.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA1.CursorX.AutoScroll = false;
                CA1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBoxYZoom_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChartArea CA1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

            if (this.checkBoxYZoom.Checked == true)
            {
                CA1.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                CA1.CursorY.AutoScroll = true;
                CA1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CA1.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA1.CursorY.AutoScroll = false;
                CA1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = false;
            }
        }
```

This is code for select areas on the chart

```
  private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
        {           

            ranges.Add(curRange);
            selectedIndices.Union(collectDataPoints(chart1.Series[0], curRange.Width, curRange.Height)).Distinct();
            StripLine sl = new StripLine();
            sl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.Coral);
            sl.IntervalOffset = Math.Min(curRange.Width, curRange.Height);
            sl.StripWidth = Math.Abs(curRange.Height - curRange.Width);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(sl);

        }
        List<int> collectDataPoints(Series s, double min, double max)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
                if (s.Points[i].XValue >= min && s.Points[i].XValue <= max) hits.Add(i);           
            return hits;
        }
        private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
        {

            curRange = new SizeF((float)e.NewSelectionStart, (float)e.NewSelectionEnd);
        }
```

This is Reset Button code;

```
private void btnReset1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset(0);
                this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset(0);
                this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Clear();
        }
```

Please give a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

User selectable zooming is enabled in two steps

```
ChartArea ca = ...;
ca.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
ca.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

enables the user to click and select areas of the charting area using the mouse. It does not implement zooming.

```
ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
```

enables interactive zooming by applying the `Cursor` user selection as the `ScaleView` settings.

So in your case your checkboxes should only toggle the `Zoomable` property like so, which will keep Cursor range selection possible even with zooming switched off:

```
private void checkBoxXZoom_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ChartArea ca = ...;
  ca.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = this.checkBoxXZoom.Checked;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help very much.I an a beginner for this language.so please If you can clarify this furthermore.

Comment: ,Sir,my problem is I can select area first time only with x or y checkbox are in true.after click the reset button and false the checkBox then I can not select area,why is that.please give me a solution for that.

Comment: Set the Cursor settings in your constructor. Only toggle the zoomable property in you checkbox event handlers.